# Detect if "player" is left or right of the middle of screen

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hello and thanks for reading this.

I'm fairly new to unity but regardless of that fact I made a little game, same stile as mario and other. A game were you Move left and right and jump to avoid enemy.

But I face a little code problem and I cant seem to find a answer anyway to help me solve it.

I need to detect if player left or right of the middle of screen, so I know if the camera have to move left or right.

This is the camera script I'm so far created.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraFunction : MonoBehaviour {

float ydir = 0f;
public GameObject player;
//for our GUIText object and our score
public GUIElement gui;
float playerScore = 0;

//this function updates our guitext object
void OnGUI(){
    gui.guiText.text = "Score: " + ((int)(playerScore * 10)).ToString ();
}
//this is generic function we can call to increase the score by an amount
public void increaseScore(int amount){
    playerScore += amount;
}
//Camera will be disabled when we load a level, set the score in playerprefs
void OnDisable(){
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Score",(int)(playerScore));
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    //check that player exists and then proceed. otherwise we get an error when player dies
    if (player) {


        if (player.transform.position.x > -1) {

            //update our score every tick of the clock
            playerScore += Time.deltaTime;

            transform.position = new Vector3 (transform.position.x + 0.03f, transform.position.y, -10);
        }
    }
}
}
```

My script only detects if the "player" pass the middle of the current view and then start moving.

I hope you understand what I mean, and will be able to help me.

**Update:**

If you look at it this way, we can split the screen in 2, the left and right part, and ofcourse we have the middle between those 2.

The person/player starts on the left side of the screen and have to move right throught the map to the end goal.

Right now when the person pass the middle and into the right of the screen the camera will start moving right. But I can't make it detect if the user/player moves backwards then he camera have to "freeze".

So if player position is > 50% of screen(Right side) = Camera move right.
If player position is < 50% of screen(Left side) = Camera "Freeze".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made a little update that hopefully explain it a bit better.

Comment: > `This is a generic function`... No, `increaseScore` is not a generic function. Generic functions have `<>` brackets, like, `DestroyAllObjects<TObject>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this in any script component attached to the camera:

```
    if(camera.WorldToScreenPoint(player.transform.position).x > Screen.width / 2){
        Debug.Log("Player is right of the middle of the screen.");
    }
```

In which `WorldToScreenPoint` is converting world coordinates to screen coordinates.

Comment: You know, you probably only need to see if the player is left or right of the camera in general because the camera "position" is represented by the center point if my memory serves correctly.

Comment: That's true, if the camera is always pointing along an axis. The question did not mention whether it is a 2D or a 3D game. So if the camera can be rotated then you need to calculate some vector math (like in my answer).